# Li-Ion Polymer battery capacity tester - like Opus Bt-3100 for 18650

Tags: battery-life, battery, test-equipment

**What**

Searching for capacity tester for LiPo batteries, which runs full cycle (charge, discharge, charge) and displays accurate battery capacity.

I am looking for same features as Opus BT-C3100, which I use for 18650 batteries ([https://www.amazon.com/Opus-BT-Intelligent-Compatible-Batteries/dp/B01852TBOU](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01852TBOU)).
[image]

**Why**

I salvage notebook batteries. 18650 are not used anymore and I need a tool to measure Li-ion Polymer cells.

[image]
[image]

I prefer a **finished** product, but you can **suggest DIY solutions**.

Comment: What kind of batteries do you need to test?

Comment: Li-ion Polymer (LiPo) flat batteries. I added images to the post.